# Loading a webpage into iFrame Flask

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, flask

I am really new to Flask. I want to create a a mobile App simulation on the web. I have found a bootstrap template that I like. I have implemented a small Flask application in python to act as the server.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is the body of the index.html file

```
<body>
    <div class="main-row">
        <h1>Fortune Estates</h1>
        <div class="main_frame">
            <iframe class="frame-border scroll-pane" src="templates/main.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="copy-right">
        <p>&copy; 2016 Fortune Estates . All Rights Reserved | Design by <a href="http://w3layouts.com" target="_blank">W3layouts</a></p>
    </div>
    <script src="static/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

        var nice = $("html").niceScroll();  // The document page (body)

        $("#div1").html($("#div1").html()+' '+nice.version);

        $("#boxscroll").niceScroll(); // First scrollable DIV

      });
    </script>
</body>
```

When I start the flask app, I get this error `127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017 14:46:45] "GET /templates/main.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

This is my file hierarchy

```
.
+-- app.py
+-- templates 
|   +-- index.html
|   +-- main.html
|   ....
+-- static 
|   +--js
|   |   +--bootstrap.cs
|   |   ...
|   +--fonts
|   |   ...
|   +--css
|   |   ...
|   +--images
|   |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referencing the main.html template from index.html which are in the same directory, try using src="main.html" in iFrame.

Then the browser will be sending another GET Request for the main.html file. You need to cover it from the server side by adding the new function in your Flask server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)


@app.route('/main.html')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Still does not load the page.
`127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017 15:39:53] "GET /main.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: Try using the edited solution, it should work just fine